# Как полностью перебрать массив объектов?

Tags: javascript

Почему метод find возвращает только первый объект с массива?

Как правильно сделать чтобы проверяло целый массив на это условие?

Сейчас работает только первый логин и пароль, а когда вводишь второй - срабатывает второе условие, хотя должно сработать первое, потому что все верно.

```js
const storedData = [
    {
        email: "ii@gmail.com",
        pw : 'qqq'     
    },

    {
        email : "pp@gmail.com",
        pw : "www"
    }
];

document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    storedData.find(data => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.email === document.querySelector('#login').value && data.pw === document.querySelector('#pw').value) {
            console.log("ok");
        }else {
            console.log("inccorect login or pw");
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

```html
 <form action="">
        login <input type="text" id="login">
        password <input type="password" id="pw">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
      </form>
```

Comment: можно использовать метод [some](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#every-some)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы используете метод `find()` не по назначению: он возвращает первый подходящий элемент (то есть элемент, для которого функция-параметр возвращает truthy значение) и дальше ничего не перебирает.

Если вам не нужно возвращаемое значение, а нужно просто перебрать весь массив с какими-то действиями, используйте `forEach()` или цикл for-of.

Или же, если при помощи `find()` нужно проверить, подходят ли данные хоть для одного элемента массива, возвращайте `true` только в случае совпадения и проверяйте возвращённое `find()` значение.

```js
const storedData = [
    {
        email: "ii@gmail.com",
        pw : 'qqq'     
    },

    {
        email : "pp@gmail.com",
        pw : "www"
    }
];

document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const found = storedData.find(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return data.email === document.querySelector('#login').value &&
               data.pw === document.querySelector('#pw').value;
    });
    
    if (found) console.log("ok");
    else console.log("inccorect login or pw");
});
```

Можно ещё использовать метод `some()`.

Comment: Хорошо метод forEach будет проверял каждый объект массива и возвращал Разные значения (и будет "ок" и затем "неверный логин и пароль"), вопрос как сделать если пароль верный остановить перебор и вывести сообщение "ок" в противном случае "неверный логин и пароль "

Comment: Запустите сначала проверку по массиву при помощи `find()` (проверьте, не равно ли значение `undefined`) или `some()` (проверьте, не равно ли значение `false`). Если таки равно, тогда уже выводите предупреждения о неправильности данных. Если элемент найден или значение не равно `false`, выводите `'ok'`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Comment: Добавил в ответ возможный вариант.

Answer (score 3):

Метод [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) останавливается, в случае, если результатом выполнения callback функции является `true`.

Так как у тебя **всегда** возвращается `true` - то поиск заканчивается сразу.

Answer (score 1):

Метод find возвращает первый элемент который удовлетворяет условию